# Символы в пути &amp;quot; Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Когда я удаляю из БД данные, мне нужно удалить и изображение с сервера. Но когда я это делаю, выдает ошибку. Как убрать эти символы и оставить только название фото в пути?

> unlink(W:\domains\sute\public\content/completed/[{&quot;img&quot;:&quot;unknown.png&quot;}]):
> No such file or directory

```
$categorysView = DB::table('categorys')
      ->where('id','=', $id)
      ->get(['img']);

unlink(public_path('content/completed/'.$categorysView));
```

Comment: посмотрите что $categorysView содержит

Comment: @InDevX ну имя фото из колонки img

Comment: var_dump или dd покажите, интересует именно что там записано а не слова

Comment: @InDevX Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1257 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#1256 ▼
      +"img": "unknown.png"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Тогда так попробуйте брать картинку `$img = DB::table('categorys')->select('img')->where('id','=', $id)->first()->img;`